# Ending the Out going call

Tags: android

[OutGoingCallEnding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714989/i-am-not-getting-the-outgoing-call-phone-number-both-in-emulator-and-real-phone)

This is my link source code, I want to ending the out going call ending particular time.after some limit time another out going call going.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599443/android-how-to-hang-up-outgoing-call/5314372#5314372

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for ending an call in android add `ITelephony.aidl` in your project and call `endCall()` method like this :

```
private void endCall() {
  //iTelephony
  Class<TelephonyManager> c = TelephonyManager.class;
  Method getITelephonyMethod = null;
  try {
   getITelephonyMethod = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony",(Class[]) null);
   getITelephonyMethod.setAccessible(true);
   ITelephony iTelephony = (ITelephony) getITelephonyMethod.invoke(mTelephonyManager, (Object[]) null);
   iTelephony.endCall();
   Log.v(this.getClass().getName(), "endCall......");
  } catch (Exception e) {
   Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "endCallError", e);
  } 
 }
```

Comment: Where is "mTelephonyManager" from ?

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.android.internal.telephony;

 interface ITelephony {


  boolean endCall();


   void answerRingingCall();


   void silenceRinger();

}
```

creating one packing save it this